# Building Uri Matcher for query parameter

Tags: android

I am buidling a uriPatternMatcher for my content provider.
My uri is like `content://com.example.wordapp/wordlist?flashid=1` which I got using Logger statement. 
What should be my pattern matcher?

I tried

```
public static final String CONTENT_AUTHORITY ="com.example.wordapp";
public static final Uri BASE_CONTENT_URI =Uri.parse("content://"+CONTENT_AUTHORITY);
public static final String PATH_WORD ="wordlist";
public static final String FLASHCARD_ID="flashid";

 matcher.addURI(authority, WordContractClass.PATH_WORD + "?"+ WordContractClass.WordListEntry.FLASHCARD_ID+"=#", WORD_WITH_FLASH_LIST);
```

The matcher is showing output as **No Match Found**.

Answer (score 0):

You are adding the pattern incorrectly. From the documentation of UriMatcher(http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/UriMatcher.html), you see that your second argument should be the path and third one should be the code against which your uri should be matched.

I am not sure what exactly you are trying to match but yours should look something like:

```
// assuming pathWord is the path to the list and WORDS_WITH_FLASH_LIST is the code that will be returned on a successful match
matcher.addURI(authority, pathWord + "/#", WORDS_WITH_FLASH_LIST);
```

The "#" implies that there are multiple entries within this path. You do not need the "?" that you currently have.

Comment: I am trying to fetch all entries having same flashId. Your answer works if I append path( / ) to my uri, not if I append query ( ? ).

Comment: You should not have query in your uri - this is how Android was designed. It does not have any use in this context